# Android - Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

i want to change the color of the actionBar, i was reading the appcelerator docs and reproduce the code with no results.

What am i doing wrong ?

**tiapp.xml**

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
       <application android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomActionBar"/>
       <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" android:maxSdkVersion="23"/>
    </manifest>     
    <manifest android:versionCode="3" android:versionName="1.0.1"/>
</android>
```

custom theme

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.CustomActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">        
    <item name="colorPrimary">#1565C0</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#0D47A1</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF80AB</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#757575</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#FF6E40</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#BDBDBD</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#BDBDBD</item>
    <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">#FF4081</item>        
    </style>
 </resources>
```

[Screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/ACSzYDblts9IR6VsaPp-xN5V2s8zjbJMf9g)

Thanks in advance..

Titanium Appcelerator 4.5
SDK: 5.2.0 GA
Genymotion

Comment: Are you using `ToolBar` or `ActionBar`? I see you are using API 23, so I would assume `ToolBar`?

Comment: that's a good question, i just copied the code from the appcelerator docs.... the docs says "Actiobar"

Comment: Ah, so not Java. Nevermind. I have no idea about the Appcelerator API.

Comment: No problem... its solved !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this line: `<manifest android:versionCode="3" android:versionName="1.0.1"/>` and put the `android:versionCode` and `android:versionName` into the first `manifest` tag.

Comment: Indeed. By duplicating `<manifest>` you let Titanium use the last one, which does not contain the theme setting.

Comment: Thank @Fokke-Appcelerator